# SSIS - Stored Procedure Output Meesages and Results to Text

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We currently have a process that calls SQLCMD in shell script that outputs the results of a stored procedure to a text log file. The stored procedure does multiple Updates, Inserts, and Select statements and we capture all the messages and results to a text file partly for having a Select statement that shows the table before it is updated and after it is updated. Now we are converting to SSIS and would like to capture both the results and messages in a text file.

I have 2 questions: Is there a way to do this without calling SQLCMD in SSIS and possibly use execute sql or data flow task? If not, what is the best practice for capturing changes? (I see that I need enterprise edition for Change Capture via SQL so that doesn't work for us.)

Edit (more explanation):

I have stored procedure that does 10 updates in a row. Before I do the update I want to see what the table looks like for that specific update query by selecting the data out of it with the same parameters as the update query. Now each update does something different but one may do something to a record that I did not expect. This will allow me to pinpoint the exact problem. The best idea suggested is triggers, although it may be slow, it can be set up to capture the changes that I need.

Comment: You could do it all in a script task, although, arguably, that defeats the purpose of SSIS.  Alternatively, you could create an audit table that contains the before/after state of the table for the life of the proc.

Comment: You could enable traces on a database and capture all DML in a separate database. Alternatively, you could also add a trigger to the tables being altered to do the same (if you do not own the enterprise edition for auditing features).

Comment: I'm rather confused by your question, could you help me understand it better? SQLCMD is roughly analogous to an Execute SQL Task within SSIS. You can pass parameters and such to it. If the scripts you were supplying to SQLCMD were tracking changes, then you can probably make an Execute SQL Task do the same. That said, you then bring up and dismiss CDC so that leads me to believe you're looking to replace your existing process with a more OOB process. If the latter, then we need to better understand your requirements

Comment: For example, assume the following sequence of events happen in an hour - I create my account. I update my account to have my avatar. I then add my birthday - do you want to track all of those changes or is it sufficient to know that the row for this account had activity today?

Comment: You could alter your existing stored procedure to write to a table instead of a outputting to a text file. I don't understand why you would have a database change data capture process that saves the changes to a... text file?

Comment: Let me give just a bit more explanation. I have stored procedure that does 10 updates in a row. Before I do the update I want to see what the table looks like for that specific update query by selecting the data out of it with the same parameters as the update statement. Now each update does something different but one may do something that I did not expect. This will allow me to pinpoint the exact problem. The best idea is triggers, although it may be slow, it will capture changes.

Comment: Yes. triggers or native CDC means that you don't need to change any scripts and you have auditing baked in no matter how you alter data